# Wordpress permalink still not working (error or not understood?)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

After hours in understanding wordpress permalinks I'm despairing and hope that somebody can help.

I have the following link:

```
www.mysite.com/?page_id=923&bahn=BER
```

After activating the permalinks the link becomes to

www.mysite.com/data/rink?bahn=BER

So far so good. But my goal is to have a link like this:

```
www.mysite.com/data/rink/BER
```

Therefor I have included the following code into my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_page_variables' );
function add_custom_page_variables( $public_query_vars ) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'bahn';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'data/rink/([^/]+)',
        'index.php?pagename=rink&bahn=$matches[1]',
    'top' );

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

I have tested this rule with a plugin which shows that the rule is activated and should be correct. But it doesn't work! When entering the URL it always "redirects" to:

```
www.mysite.com/data/rink or www.mysite.com/data/rink?bahn=BER
```

Can someone point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: If `rink` is a child page of `data`, then `pagename` should be `data/rink`.

Comment: I have changed it to "index.php?pagename=data/rink&bahn=$matches[1]" but it doesn't have an effect :-(

Comment: when I enter "www.mysite.com/?page_id=923&bahn=BER" it now shows me "www.mysite.com/data/rink/?bahn=BER" in the browser adress line BUT redirects me to "www.mysite.com/data/rink"...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution by myself. I forgot to access the variable via $wp_query->query_vars['bahn']. It works fine now.

BUT unfortunatly, the URL is still not correct shown or translated in the browser address line. It allways shows me

```
www.mysite.com/data/rink/?bahn=BER
```

but I would like to see

```
www.mysite.com/data/rink/BER
```

How can this be realized?